# read ckeditor content

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor in my asp.net page. For this i have added ckeditor.dll to my project.
And i am using this reference in .aspx page.
My problem is that i can not able to read ckeditor content in javascipt.
Can any one please tell me how to achive this.
Here is my code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CKEditorVamshi._Default" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="CKEditor.NET" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" TagPrefix="CKEditor" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function validate() {
            var text = $('#cke_<%= CKEditorGettingStarted.ClientID %> iframe').contents().find('body').html();
           alert(text);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <CKEditor:CKEditorControl AutoPostBack="True" ID="CKEditorGettingStarted" runat="server"
    Height="300px" BasePath="~/CKEditor" MaxLength="10" Width="100%" CausesValidation="true">
 </CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
 <br />
 <input type="button" id="btnPreview" value="Preview" onclick="validate();" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 1):

try

`CKEDITOR.instances.Your_Editor_Client_ID.getData();`